# google "i am feeling lucky" by url has sensative words?

Tags: javascript, web, fetch, google-search

I am not too sure where to ask it, but I have an odd problem with my automate google I am feeling lucky function I am using in my code.

That appears to be a problem with the google search itself.
I've been using javascript node-fetch by calling the URL `http://www.google.com/search?q=${string}&btnI`
This URL provides me with the result of the "I am feeling lucky" google result, everything seemed to be working fine until I tried to pass it the word "alvastia", then it performs a regular search.

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=alvastia&btnI // results in regular google search.
http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI // results in the stackoverflow page as result of I am feeling lucky
```

What am I missing here??

Comment: If your mysterious problem is a problem of Google's search engine, why not ask them about this?

Comment: How can I ask them about it?